# Multiple Opa Web Apps On One Server

Tags: opa

I currently have multiple websites set up with the standard Apache virtual host configuration.

My question is how do I set up multiple websites built using Opa so that they run like they would with to with Apache virtual hosts.

ex. When a user types in www.example1.com the server redirects the user to OpaApp1 OR When a user types in www.example2.com the server redirects the user to OpaApp2

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the requested host with [HttpRequest.get_host()](http://doc.opalang.org/#!/value/stdlib.core.web.request/HttpRequest/get_host).

A sample app :

```
OpaApp1 = {{
  start(uri) = Resource.html("Hello", <>World 1</>)
}}

OpaApp2 = {{
  start(uri) = Resource.html("Hello", <>World 2</>)
}}

@server
start(uri:Uri.relative) =
  match HttpRequest.get_host()
  {some={some="www.example1.com"}} -> OpaApp1.start(uri)
  {some={some="www.example2.com"}} -> OpaApp2.start(uri)
  _ -> Resource.error_page("Error", <>Bad gateway</>, {bad_gateway}) // default

server = Server.simple_dispatch(start)
```

Comment: Thanks,
Does this mean I can compile OpaApp1.opa, OpaApp2.opa, and SomeRequestRedirectionApp.opa separately?
Then as I add more OpaAppX.opa websites could I simply add a small addition to SomeRequestRedirectionApp.opa?

Comment: No you have to compile it into one single binary. You can make different packages (for every apps), but it must in the end, end up in one binary.

Comment: Otherwise, i recommend using a load balancer like [nginx](http://www.nginx.com/) in front of your different web apps, and load balance them with nginx. This is a good solution because Opa is not multi-threaded (yet), so you will take advantage of your multi-core processor if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Apache guru, but I suppose you can configure different domains for different ports in which case you can run different Opa apps on different ports (`--port` switch). That may be more modular than just having one global app.